# If statement in JAVA giving error

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
       if(5>10)                                        
          System.out.println("5>10");
       if(true)         
          System.out.println("true");
       if((3+6)==(3-6))           
          System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

the output is string: true (the second if statement been processed)

I don't understand why `if(true) System.out.println("true");` will be processed and print out true. The condition `true` in the `if` statement refers to nowhere. I get this code from my textbook. The default value of boolean in Java should be false, then why the second `if` statement can be printed out?

Comment: if the statement in the `if` statement is true it will execute the code block. So therefore `if(true)` will always be true and therefore always print out true

Comment: How does this not make sense?  When is `true` ever not `true`?

Comment: A default boolean variable might be initialized to `false` but you're specifically passing in the value `true`.

Comment: The default value of `true` should be `false` ... that is a really strange request, OP.

Comment: If you had it call `System.out.println("false")` then it wouldn't execute because it wouldn't match.

Comment: @LukePark A double positive should be the logical complement of a double negative, right? So two rights make a wrong.

Comment: @EdPlunkett But there's just one right...

Comment: @LukePark Hmmm. You may have a point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the if-statement will be executed if the evaluation result in the condition (in the parentheses (condition)) resulting in true, regardless of what the condition is. As long as the condition is true, you will enter the if-block. And as long as the condition if false, the if-block will not be entered.

And thats why your first and last if:

```
if(5>10) //false
if((3+6)==(3-6)) //false
```

Will never be entered as they always result in false (thus, nothing is printed as well).

That being said, though useless, people can also put true or false directly in the if statement as a condition:

```
if(true)
```

Which make its block will always be executed or not executed if it is true or false respectively.

The real use of the "true" as checking condition normally comes with infinite loop:

```
while(true){
  //do something infinitely till break or error
}
```

But I don't think

```
 if(true)
```

Has any real use.

Answer (score 0):

`true` here is a `boolean`.  It would be the same as

```
boolean first = true;
boolean second = false;
if (first) {
    System.out.println("first");
}
if (second) {
    System.out.println("second");
}
```

This will output "first" only.

Comment: This will give a compilation error as `third` is not initialized and is not a class member

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why if(true) System.out.println("true"); will be processed and print out true.

You should really learn about conditional statements in general. [Here's one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm) that talks about `IF` statements.

The syntax is

```
if(Boolean_expression){
   //Executes when the Boolean expression is true
}else{
   //Executes when the Boolean expression is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why if(true) System.out.println("true"); will be processed and print out true. The condition(true) in the if statement refer to nowhere. I get this code from my textbook. The default value of boolean in Java should be false, then why the second if statement can be printed out?

Actually. you're not using [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12) in the code; there is a `boolean` [literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.3) which is `true`. So, in that sense, it doesn't matter what (literal) value a Java [`boolean` variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.1) is assigned by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing informal language with computing. In informal language, "true" doesn't mean anything on its own - some statement has to *be* true. So for example, "1+1=2" is true, "the sky is blue" is true, but we would never just say "true" is true.

In computing you can. After `if`, you can put something like `5 > 1` or `2 == 9`, but you can also just write `true` or `false`.

If you find that confusing, you can just think about `if (true)` as being the same as `if (0 == 0)` and `if (false)` as being the same as `if (0 == 1)`.